# WHY my ssh key not generating from gitbash after following all the mentioned command on github site?

Tags: mingw, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

After using several commands from githun site

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Still my ssh key has been not generated Screenshot as below -

[image]

I tried several commans from official github website

Comment: 1. Don't paste screenshots, only text here 2. Learn format of command-line and **never** add crappy-chars, the meaning of which you do not understand or it is unknown - you have leading-shit in form of "$" in 2-5 and "~" in 7-9 (and totally crazy nonsensical 1+6)

Answer (score 1):

The `$` is not supposed to be typed: it is a prompt symbol, not the actual command.

Using `ssh-keygen` directly (without $ in ofromt of it) should work just fine.
It is part of Git for Windows (`C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\ssh-keygen.exe`), and in a git bash session, it is part of the default `$PATH` (`/usr/bin/ssh-keygen`).

I just tried it:

```bash
vonc@vclp MINGW64 ~/
$ ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "YOUR_EMAIL" -P ""
Generating public/private ed25519-sk key pair.
You may need to touch your authenticator to authorize key generation.
Key enrollment failed: device not found
```

I did not type `$`. It is just what the prompt displayed, before I copy-pasted `ssh-keygen -t ed25519-sk -C "YOUR_EMAIL" -P ""`